# How should I best search through a custom list generated dynamically based on id for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So, I have this scenario where I have a list of div elements of a class 'item', and want to traverse through those elements for elements with a specific attribute.

Example HTML:

```
<div> 
    <div class='item' data-id='bob123'>Bob</div>
    <div class='item' data-id='tedddd'>Ted</div>
    <div class='item' data-id='mikester'>Mike</div>
    <div class='item' data-id='joeyboy'>Joe</div>
</div>
```

With that list, my current method of selecting a specific element is through the dataset property, where I store a person's id under data-id.

Using JQuery, I have:

```
var specificElement = $('.item[data-id=(user id)]);
```

Then, I perform operations on that element such as highlighting, showing and hiding.

Now, my dilemma is whether this is actually an efficient method of sifting through the list, since I heard that accessing dataset could be slow.

Should I change my HTML schema and store the id a different way (such as using a classlist)? I am hesitant on marking each with an id such as user_bob123 since I feel like that could *potentially* create conflicts within the rest of the html, even though that would allow access just by

```
document.getElementById('user_' + id);
```

I am open to suggestions, and since selecting elements are a common part of my application I want to be sure to do that as efficiently as possible.

Comment: `since I heard that accessing dataset could be slow.` Is it actually causing any issues in your application, or are you just worried that it "might" be slow at some point? My 2 cents is that if it doesn't appear to be causing any obvious bottleneck, I wouldn't worry too much about it. The way you're going about it seems fine... probably not worth the milliseconds or so that you may or may not be saving by going with another method.

Comment: Yea, I'm partly worrying that it "might" be slow at some point, and partly trying to see how somebody more experienced with JS would look at this problem. The application as it stands is running fine, and runs the operation twice per user click on a list.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Just as an example, there are a multitude of frameworks in heavy use doing things way "worse" that that (see Angular, React, etc.) Not saying "because a popular framework does it, then it's right", but instead that it's really a micro-optimization at this point. As far as the second thing you said: `runs the operation twice per user click on a list`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: My application has a contact list as well as a recent messages list. Both open up a chat window, and highlight the person being selected. It finds the element for the user in both lists, and updates the highlight to being on the right person. i.e. bob is clicked on the contact list, bob should now be selected in the recent messages list as well. My application does a lot of dynamic interaction with those lists for chat as well as notifications and such, which was why I was concerned about the performance aspect of selecting the right element per user. I appreciate your feedback by the way!

Comment: In my experience, I would say the performance impacts would be negligible. I'd love to hear others' opinions on the issue, though.

Comment: My advice: avoid micro optimizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no concept of *dataset* in HTML5. These `data-` attributes are just *custom attributes*. That is, there's no additional overhead when retrieving elements by using a selector than it could have any other case, excepting when you get *by id* (i.e. `document.getElementById`), which may be optimized by the browser storing both ids and elements in a *hash table* for fast access.

BTW, if you want to optimize this access to elements with `data-id`, you should be able to store references of these elements in an object and access them using regular JavaScript functions:

```js
// Vanilla JS!!
var items = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".item[data-id]"))
  .reduce(function(result, currentElement) {
    result[currentElement.getAttribute("data-id")] = $(currentElement);
    return result;
  }, {});

// Now access these elements by id, and you won't need to query the document
// anymore. Accessing object properties is actually faster than a selector:
var bob123Element = items["bob123"];

setTimeout(function() {
  bob123Element.hide();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='item' data-id='bob123'>Bob</div>
  <div class='item' data-id='tedddd'>Ted</div>
  <div class='item' data-id='mikester'>Mike</div>
  <div class='item' data-id='joeyboy'>Joe</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very true. I will heavily consider switching to this model.

Comment: @DavidLi BTW my advise is you should switch to use a data-binding capable library or framework. Knockout, Angular, Aurelia, React, ... It makes this even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use ID and save a programmatic reference for future access so you don't have to keep traversing the DOM.

```
var users = {
    bob123: $('#user_bob123'),
    tedddd: $('#user_tedddd')
};
```

Then for future access, without traversing the DOM again:

```
users.bob123.hide();
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea that didn't cross my mind. Thanks for the input!